# C#: String parameter being mysteriously reset to empty - please help!

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, expression-trees

I'm experimenting with parsing expression trees and have written the following code:

```
private void TestExpressionTree()
  {
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> expression = x => x == 1 || x == 2;
    string output = String.Empty;
    HandleExpression(expression.Body, output);
    Output("Output", output);
  }

  private void HandleExpression(Expression expression, string output)
  {
    switch (expression.NodeType)
    {
      case ExpressionType.Conditional:
        HandleConditionalExpression(expression, output);
        break;
      case ExpressionType.OrElse:
        HandleOrElseExpression(expression, output);
        break;
      case ExpressionType.Equal:
        HandleEqualExpression(expression, output);
        break;
      case ExpressionType.Parameter:
        HandleParameterExpression(expression, output);
        break;
      case ExpressionType.Constant:
        HandleConstantExpression(expression, output);
        break;
    }
  }

  private void HandleConditionalExpression(Expression expression, string output)
  {
    ConditionalExpression conditionalExpression = (ConditionalExpression) expression;
    HandleExpression(conditionalExpression.Test, output);
  }

  private void HandleOrElseExpression(Expression expression, string output)
  {
    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)expression;
    HandleExpression(binaryExpression.Left, output);
    output += "||";
    HandleExpression(binaryExpression.Right, output);
  }

  private void HandleEqualExpression(Expression expression, string output)
  {
    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)expression;
    HandleExpression(binaryExpression.Left, output);
    output += "=";
    HandleExpression(binaryExpression.Right, output);
  }

  private void HandleParameterExpression(Expression expression, string output)
  {
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression = (ParameterExpression)expression;
    output += parameterExpression.Name;
  }

  private void HandleConstantExpression(Expression expression, string output)
  {
    ConstantExpression constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)expression;
    output += constantExpression.Value.ToString();
  }
```

The idea of the code is to parse the expression tree and write details about the nodes into the string variable output. However, when this variable is written to the page (using the `Output()` method), I'm finding it's empty.

When I use the debugger to step through the code, I find that output is correctly set to 'x' when the code executes `HandleParameterExpression()` for the first time, but as soon as control returns from `HandleParameterExpression()` back to the switch block in `HandleExpression()`, the variable is mysteriously empty again.

Since strings are reference types, I should simply be able to pass the reference between the methods and changes to its value made by the methods should be retained, right? Is there some subtlety of parameter passing in C# that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Easy tigers! Four answers in five minutes! Massive thank yous to everyone!

Comment: Why aren't you returning the modified output? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Omar: because I don't need to. It is possible to use methods to modify parameters as well as just returning something.

Comment: @David - But Omar is correct in his assumption - the standard way of doing something like this is to return a value. Following standard coding conventions makes your code better because more people understand it more easily.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm starting to think I was having some sort of mental episode when I wrote this. I blame my teething son.

Comment: Having said that, returning the output string would suggest semantically that creating the output string is the entire purpose of the methods. Whereas in fact it was just a way to test I was parsing the expression tree correctly. I think in future I may modify the code to do different things depending on why I want to parse the expression tree. So I might pass in some object implementing a standard interface which does some particular thing in response to the analysis of the expression tree - for example, building a string. But that's probably more madness. Maybe tomorrow it will make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass in ANY variable that you want to actually change by reference. So, in your example, you would need to do it this way:

```
private void HandleOrElseExpression(Expression expression, ref string output)
```

And then when you call the function, you would do it this way:

```
HandleOrElseExpression(expression, ref output)
```

Comment: So if I pass in a class instance to a method which is intended to change its state, I need to explicitly pass by reference! I swear I've never passed anything by reference, and I've never had this problem before...

Comment: If you are passing in an object and are setting properties on it or calling methods on it, then no, you do not need to pass it by reference. But if you want to set that object as another instance of it (like saying myObject = new Object(), then you do need to pass it by reference (or as an output parameter, as Botz3000 mentioned) to be able to use the new value outside the function.

Comment: @David: No, if you're changing the state of an *object*, you don't need to pass by reference. It's if you're trying to change *which object a variable refers to* that you want to consider using `ref`.

Answer (score 8):

You're never changing the data *within* the string, because it's immutable.

Each time you have:

```
output += something;
```

that's saying:

```
output = output + something;
```

The value of "output + something" is actually the result of calling `String.Concat(output, something)` - i.e. a reference to a new string. So your code is changing the value of the *variable* `output` to refer to the new string. The data in the existing string remains unchanged.

Changing the value of a parameter *won't* change the corresponding value in the caller, unless the parameter is passed by reference (using `ref` or `out`). See my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details. Note the difference between passing a reference by value, and passing a variable by reference.

I suggest you change your code to use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: I always thought that reference types (e.g. strings) were passed by reference BY DEFAULT. I thought that was what the name meant...

Comment: @David: No, it means the value of an expression of that type is a reference to an object containing the data, rather than storing the data itself. Read my article for details.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, so by assigning another value to `output`, you are not changing `output`, but creating a new string variable.

You might want to declare the `output` parameter as `ref`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use `out` params:

Example: Change `private void HandleExpression(Expression expression, string output)` to `private void HandleExpression(Expression expression, out string output)` and replace `HandleExpression(expression.Body, output);` with `HandleExpression(expression.Body, out output);`
Then writing to `output` in the method will affect the argument passed to the function.